# Extend imported object then export it again?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Is it possible to import something, add more to it, then export it again?

I am experimenting with ways of making intelisense friendly constants

Is something like this doable?

Core/constants.js

```
const REST:{
   LOGIN: '/login',
   LOGOUT: '/logout'
}
const PROFILE:{
   GET_PROFILE: '/get-profile',
   DELETE_PROFILE: '/delete-profile'
}
export {REST, PROFILE}
```

Custom/constants.js

```
import core from 'Core/constants.js'
const LOCATION:{
   LOCATE_USER: '/locate-user-by-device'
}

export {LOCATION, core}
```

page.js

```
import {REST as r, LOCATION as l} from 'Custom/constants.js'
```

Where you only need to import the custom version, the custom version contains all the core information.

The idea is that the core versions of files exist in a git subtree that are shared between projects

Comment: Could you elaborate on the idea of 'extend'? The code in `Custom/constants.js` is currently just importing constants from `Core/constants.js` and then exporting them, not  changing or augmenting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
// Core/constants.js
export const REST = {
   LOGIN: '/login',
   LOGOUT: '/logout'
};
export const PROFILE = {
   GET_PROFILE: '/get-profile',
   DELETE_PROFILE: '/delete-profile'
};
```

```
// Custom/constants.js
export * from 'Core/constants.js'
export const LOCATION = {
   LOCATE_USER: '/locate-user-by-device'
};
```

This exports `REST`, `PROFILE` and `LOCATION` from the custom constants.

Comment: I didn't know you could export more than once like that and export like an import.  Thank you, that was the missing piece of information

Comment: Unsure why, but this makes my jest test script mad. 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: "module"'   Removing the `export * from 'Core/constants.js'` makes it happy.  Any ideas?

Comment: @TrevorD That's weird. I can't see no reason why it would accept `export const` but not `export * from`. Or maybe you missed to declared `Core/constants.js` as `sourceType: "module"`?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @TrevorD I have no idea about your toolchain (and not much experience either, so this probably should be a new question that can be answered by someone else), but if my hunch was correct then you did declare it for `Custom/constants.js` already but not for `Core/constants.js`.